# Kotlin Generics Constraints

Tags: generics, jvm, kotlin

Имеется код следующего вида:

```
data class Vec2<T : Number>(val x : T, val y : T) {
    public operator fun plus(v : Vec2<T>) : Vec2<T> = Vec2(this.x + v.x, this.y + v.y); }
```

Проблема в том, что в Number нет никаких интерфейсов типа Addable, ну и в потомках тоже. Возможно ли как-то избежать написания реализации под каждый тип отдельно?

Проблему бы решило, если бы в ограничениях generic можно было бы указать несколько возможных типов (что-то вроде T: (Float|Int|Double)), либо как-то проверять, содержится ли нужный метод в подставляемом классе (это уже duck typing какой-то)